# SDL2 IMG_LoadTexture can't find the texture from asset - Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, sdl-image

I'm trying to understand why SDL2 compiled for Android can't find the JPG (or bmp,or png) texture file using this code:

```
/** Prepare textures */
static SDL_Texture *img = NULL;
int w, h; // texture width & height
          // load our image

if (img == NULL) {
    img = IMG_LoadTexture(state->renderers[0], "background.jpg");

    if (img != NULL)
    {
        SDL_Log("Image loaded ok %s\n", "background.jpg");
    } else {
        SDL_Log("Error loading Image: %s\n", "background.jpg");
    }
```

I'm adding the background.jpg file in the assets folder of the project and it is added to the APK file, so I don't know what's happening, if you know something i'm missing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the sdl image library was not being initialized with IMG_INIT(flags) and you have to compile sdl image with load_jpg parameter set in the compiler. 
Once you do both things you are ready to go